# Problem with Process Builder as it is not flagging the correct titles

Tags: process-builder

I have the following logic in a process builder. The logic around titles does not appear to be working as I am seeing a lot of titles not on this list. I am trying to flag all records that has the [Lead].ActionCadenceId field populated and fulfills **one** of the other criteria that is shown below with an *. I greatly appreciate any help on this!

*titles that I am trying to flag are any titles that have the following in the title: CIO, CTO, CSO, CISO, VP, AVP, CMO,COO, Vice
President, President, Chief Information Officer, Chief Technology
Officer, Chief Security Officer, Chief Information Security Officer,
Chief Marketing Officer, Area Vice President, Chief Operational
Officer. As "cto" is in the word Director and "coo" is in the word
coordinator, I added separate flagging for CTO and COO to ensure that
I am not flagging Directors and Coordinators.

*Lead Status as shown below

*Lead Type as shown below

*Has Opted out of emails

*Lead Status Detail of Meeting/Demo

*[Lead].Account__r.of_Opportunities__c is greater than 0

*[Lead].Company contains what is mentioned below

*[Lead].Email contains what is mentioned below

Thank you!

Here is the current logic:

```
AND(
NOT(ISNULL([Lead].ActionCadenceId)),

OR(
ISPICKVAL ([Lead].Status,"Disqualified"),

ISPICKVAL ([Lead].Status,"Converted - Opportunity"),

ISPICKVAL ([Lead].Status,"Converted - No Opp"),

CONTAINS("ProofPoint:Proofpont:Mimecast:Barracuda:Fortinet:Avanon:Agari:Ironscales:Zix:Cyron:Material Security:Area 1 Security:Vade Secure:VadeSecure:Graphus",[Lead].Company),

CONTAINS("@graphus.ai:@vadesecure.com:@zix.com",[Lead].Email),

ISPICKVAL([Lead].Lead_Type__c,"Customer"),

ISPICKVAL([Lead].Lead_Type__c,"Competitor"),

[Lead].HasOptedOutOfEmail = true,

ISPICKVAL([Lead].Lead_Status_Detail__c,"Meeting/Demo"),

CONTAINS("VP:vp:AVP:avp:CISO:ciso:CEO:ceo:CFO:cfo:CSO:cso:CMO:cmo:Deputy CIO:CIO:cio:Chief Information Security Officer:Chief Security Officer:Chief Executive Officer:Chief Technology Officer:Chief Operational Officer:Chief Marketing Officer:Chief Financial Officer:President:president:Vice President:vice president:Area Vice President:area vice president",[Lead].Title),

[Lead].Title ="CTO",

[Lead].Title ="cto",

[Lead].Title ="Director, CTO Business Services",

[Lead].Title ="COO",

[Lead].Title ="Coo",

[Lead].Title ="coo",

[Lead].Title ="IT Chief & General (CIO Technology Executive & Officer",

[Lead].Title ="Associate CIO, Business Integration",

[Lead].Title ="Interim CIO",

[Lead].Account__r.of_Opportunities__c>0))
```

Comment: You have many other conditions in the OR section that could match records with Titles you don't want.  Best way to troubleshoot is to start with a partial version of the formula and gradually add sections until it stop working

Comment: create formula fields on Lead like `IsExecutive__c` and debug that formula before worrying about the Process Builder logic which is already unnecessarily opaque